# Creating a flag for the next hour after the last non-zero value

Tags: r, function, dataframe, time-series, flags

I have a data frame with dummy data:

```
library("lubridate")
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame(

  time = seq.POSIXt(from = ymd_hms("2017-05-12 00:00:00"), to = ymd_hms("2017-05-12 02:25:00"), by = "5 mins"),

  value = c(rep(0, 10), 1500, 0, 1000, rep(0,17))

)
```

which looks like this:

```
                  time value

1  2017-05-12 00:00:00     0

2  2017-05-12 00:05:00     0

3  2017-05-12 00:10:00     0

4  2017-05-12 00:15:00     0

5  2017-05-12 00:20:00     0

6  2017-05-12 00:25:00     0

7  2017-05-12 00:30:00     0

8  2017-05-12 00:35:00     0

9  2017-05-12 00:40:00     0

10 2017-05-12 00:45:00     0

11 2017-05-12 00:50:00  1500

12 2017-05-12 00:55:00     0

13 2017-05-12 01:00:00  1000

14 2017-05-12 01:05:00     0

15 2017-05-12 01:10:00     0

16 2017-05-12 01:15:00     0

17 2017-05-12 01:20:00     0

18 2017-05-12 01:25:00     0

19 2017-05-12 01:30:00     0

20 2017-05-12 01:35:00     0

21 2017-05-12 01:40:00     0

22 2017-05-12 01:45:00     0

23 2017-05-12 01:50:00     0

24 2017-05-12 01:55:00     0

25 2017-05-12 02:00:00     0

26 2017-05-12 02:05:00     0

27 2017-05-12 02:10:00     0

28 2017-05-12 02:15:00     0

29 2017-05-12 02:20:00     0

30 2017-05-12 02:25:00     0
```

I want to create a flag variable to indicate activity, and it will include the instant when the value is greater than zero, as well as the next full hour as '1'/'on'.

So, if there is 1500 value at 00:50 then the activity should last until and including 01:50.

If there's another non-zero value within that period, then the activity has to continue for the next hour too.

The final product will look something like this:

```
                 time value flag

1  2017-05-12 00:00:00     0  OFF

2  2017-05-12 00:05:00     0  OFF

3  2017-05-12 00:10:00     0  OFF

4  2017-05-12 00:15:00     0  OFF

5  2017-05-12 00:20:00     0  OFF

6  2017-05-12 00:25:00     0  OFF

7  2017-05-12 00:30:00     0  OFF

8  2017-05-12 00:35:00     0  OFF

9  2017-05-12 00:40:00     0  OFF

10 2017-05-12 00:45:00     0  OFF

11 2017-05-12 00:50:00  1500   ON

12 2017-05-12 00:55:00     0   ON

13 2017-05-12 01:00:00  1000   ON

14 2017-05-12 01:05:00     0   ON

15 2017-05-12 01:10:00     0   ON

16 2017-05-12 01:15:00     0   ON

17 2017-05-12 01:20:00     0   ON

18 2017-05-12 01:25:00     0   ON

19 2017-05-12 01:30:00     0   ON

20 2017-05-12 01:35:00     0   ON

21 2017-05-12 01:40:00     0   ON

22 2017-05-12 01:45:00     0   ON

23 2017-05-12 01:50:00     0   ON  <-- first occurrence stops having effect

24 2017-05-12 01:55:00     0   ON  <-- effect of second occurrence

25 2017-05-12 02:00:00     0   ON  <-- continues the activity then stops

26 2017-05-12 02:05:00     0  OFF

27 2017-05-12 02:10:00     0  OFF

28 2017-05-12 02:15:00     0  OFF

29 2017-05-12 02:20:00     0  OFF

30 2017-05-12 02:25:00     0  OFF
```

I frankly have no clue how to breakdown this task into a feasible for loop or a function. Any help, or clues are highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @akrun, I have some code foundation. However, now I am trying to make sure that the function also picks up any following non-zero values, just like the `1000` after `1500`, and continues the activity flag from the last non-zero value, not the first one.

by akrun:

```
time                value flag 
   <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>
 1 2017-05-12 00:00:00     0 OFF  
 2 2017-05-12 00:05:00     0 OFF  
 3 2017-05-12 00:10:00     0 OFF  
 4 2017-05-12 00:15:00     0 OFF  
 5 2017-05-12 00:20:00     0 OFF  
 6 2017-05-12 00:25:00     0 OFF  
 7 2017-05-12 00:30:00     0 OFF  
 8 2017-05-12 00:35:00     0 OFF  
 9 2017-05-12 00:40:00     0 OFF  
10 2017-05-12 00:45:00     0 OFF  
11 2017-05-12 00:50:00  1500 ON   
12 2017-05-12 00:55:00     0 ON   
13 2017-05-12 01:00:00  1000 ON   
14 2017-05-12 01:05:00     0 ON   
15 2017-05-12 01:10:00     0 ON   
16 2017-05-12 01:15:00     0 ON   
17 2017-05-12 01:20:00     0 ON   
18 2017-05-12 01:25:00     0 ON   
19 2017-05-12 01:30:00     0 ON   
20 2017-05-12 01:35:00     0 ON   
21 2017-05-12 01:40:00     0 ON   
22 2017-05-12 01:45:00     0 ON   
23 2017-05-12 01:50:00     0 ON   
24 2017-05-12 01:55:00     0 OFF  <-- wrongly flagged as OFF
25 2017-05-12 02:00:00     0 OFF  <-- wrongly flagged as OFF
26 2017-05-12 02:05:00     0 OFF  
27 2017-05-12 02:10:00     0 OFF  
28 2017-05-12 02:15:00     0 OFF  
29 2017-05-12 02:20:00     0 OFF  
30 2017-05-12 02:25:00     0 OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a grouping variable based on the occurence of 'value'  greater than  with `cumsum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
    group_by(ind = cummax(value > 0)) %>%
   group_by(group2 =  cumsum(time >  (time[1] + hours(1))), add = TRUE) %>% 
   mutate(flag = c("OFF", "ON")[1 + (any(value > 0))]) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   select(-ind, -group2)
```

Comment: hi, could you explain this code a bit? It is already a great help, but the documentation on the methods is a bit terse.

First, as I am understanding, we use `cummax(value > 0)` to find the beginning of the activity, however, it doesn't necessarily capture any following values below the first one. That's why it missed the 1000, and failed to include  `01:50:00` and `01:55:00`.

Comment: @kiyanuDevs  Sorry, I didn't get your comments.  Based on the example, it is giving me the expected output.  Are you saying ithat it is failing on your original data?

Comment: I apologize, perhaps I wasn't clear when stating the desired output. In ideal, I want the flag to pick up every value that is larger than zero, and register it as ON for the next hour, even there is _overlap_. 
You can see what I am trying to get at if you expand the dataframe: 
`df <- data.frame(
  
  time = seq.POSIXt(from = ymd_hms("2017-05-12 00:00:00"), to = ymd_hms("2017-05-12 04:55:00"), by = "5 mins"),
  
  value = c(rep(0, 10), 1500, 2000, rep(0,23), 1500,  rep(0,24))
  
)`

This is a vital part to the problem, as I am planning to apply this function on a big scale.

Answer (score 0):

After taking some time to think about it, I decided to try use a `for` loop.

Here's my own solution:

```
df$flag = "OFF"

for (i in which(df$value != 0)) {

  df$flag[i:(i+12)] = "ON"

}
```

If anyone knows how to recode this in the syntax of dplyr, could you help?